# Angularjs ng-required not clear the notification after closing model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Angularjs ng-required for form validation. When I am trying to save with blank form it shows error to fill values. After I close the model and reopen the model form validation notification is not getting cleared.
`Sample`[Plnkr Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/OxFlvVeUhjMVaJEqhpPB?p=preview)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your form on modal's close. You should call a reset function of modal close button. Please see below code and make necessary changes.
In your template please call reset function on ng-click-

```
ng-click="reset();"
```

There are many ways to set your form in prestine state, copy your form data in temporary object is one of them. like

```
$scope.mainForm = angular.copy($scope.new_visa);
```

And in your controller, please define a reset function with below code.

```
$scope.reset = function (){
        $scope.submitted = false;
        $scope.new_visa = angular.copy($scope.mainForm);
        $scope.visa_form.$setPristine();
      }
```

`$setPristine` function will set form to presitine state. It is very useful when we reuse our form after submitting or reset. A working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eEH0tEZwyLzbDmG24Ktu?p=preview) is here to check your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$setPristine();` method to reset your form. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine)

You can make the call something like this:
 `$scope.myForm.$setPrestine();`

Comment: Put up your code or detail its snippet so that I can try and help.

Comment: Check out this code http://plnkr.co/edit/LB1MbDxjwzG0UQ4K63ya. See line number 19 and 20. `myForm` is the `name` of the form element.